# Show that $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$. Show that $\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\}$ is linearly independent.
Just looking for a place to start thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $au+bv=0$, where $\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, $$(au+bv)\cdot u=0$$ or

$$a(u\cdot u)+b(v\cdot u)=0$$ or
$$a(u\cdot u)=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yup thank you $a(u\cdot u)=0$, or $a||u^2||=0$ but $u\neq 0$ so we must have $a=0$.

Comment: This means $bv$=0 but we know $v$ is nonzero so we must have $b=0$ and this extends to all vectors in $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

Comment: @squenshl It means $b(v\cdot v)=0$, $b\|v\|^2=0$ and from here $b=0$.

Comment: Is that because you took the dot product of $au+bv$ and $v$?

Comment: @squenshl Yes, of course!

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the case of only two vectors, linear dependence for nonzero vectors just means

$u=\alpha\,v\quad$ with $\alpha\neq 0$, in which case $u\cdot v=\alpha||v||^2\neq 0$.

The contraposition gives $u\cdot v=0\implies\{u,v\}$ linearly independent.